# editable PDF to Non-Editable/Read Only after filling in the acro-fields using Itext 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, itext7

Ok so I have this PDF that's a Edit-able PDF that needs to be like that to be able to fill in the Acro-Fields using this code:

```
   string src = @"C:\Test.pdf";
        string dest = @"C:\TestDone.pdf";
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);

        reader.SetUnethicalReading(true);
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(dest)); PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
        IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();
        PdfFormField toSet;
 fields.TryGetValue("Name", out toSet);
                toSet.SetValue(NameString);
```

The problem is when it saves the copy of this its still edit able the user can easily change the vlues after the PDF copy they get. Is there a way we could have this to save no-editable copy of the PDF after it fills in the form?
I looked around and a lot pf people says add the Encrypted Pass word on the PDF but that's not the approach I have here I need it to be open for the use of the employees and when the Client gets the copy make it No-Editable I am using iText7 the latest version.
Thanks is Advance.

Comment: You could set the fields read-only or you could flatten the form.

Comment: Flatten the form- I will look into that let me research on that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So just to answer this question with the Code that you need to get this done Like @mkl suggested use flatten: here is what you could do

```
string src = @"C:\Test.pdf";
string dest = @"C:\TestDone.pdf";

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
reader.SetUnethicalReading(true);
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(dest)); 

PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();
PdfFormField toSet;
fields.TryGetValue("Name", out toSet);
toSet.SetValue(NameString);

PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true).FlattenFields(); // Add this line
```

This is very easy to do so as you could see this answer was found on iText Official Site: [Flattening a form](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/clone-flattening-form)

Comment: Thank you it worked! exactly what I needed saved me a re-search

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I used to make a PDF readonly with `itext7` api. There are two passwords that can be set on a document, `Owner` and `User`. You can leave the user password as `null` so any user can open it without any password restrictions. The `EncryptionConstants` class has multiple fields such as `ALLOW_SCREENREADER`, `ALLOW_COPY`, and `ALLOW_ASSEMBLY`, etc. that can be used for PDF permission restrictions.

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.EncryptionConstants;                                                                 

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf. WriterProperties;                                                                        

import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;

 

final String OWNER_PASSWORD = "Security";

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

WriterProperties wp = new WriterProperties();

wp.setStandardEncryption(null, OWNER_PASSWORD.getBytes(), EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING,EncryptionConstants.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);

writer = new PdfWriter( baos, wp );

PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);

Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
```